# How to append data JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, json

Hello i have a json file with data exists like this

```
[
  {
    "employee": {
      "firstName": "Rudi",
      "lastName": "Anton"
    }
  },
  {
    "employee": {
      "firstName": "Syafira",
      "lastName": "Zarakaria"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to append json data to this file.

My code now not appending data, re-write file.

Help me

This is my code

```
    JSONObject employeeDetails = new JSONObject();
    employeeDetails.put("firstName", "Justin");
    employeeDetails.put("lastName", "Saklitinov");

    JSONObject employeeObject = new JSONObject(); 
    employeeObject.put("employee", employeeDetails);


    JSONObject employeeDetails2 = new JSONObject();
    employeeDetails2.put("firstName", "Zara");
    employeeDetails2.put("lastName", "Lovez");

    JSONObject employeeObject2 = new JSONObject(); 
    employeeObject2.put("employee", employeeDetails2);

    //Add employees to list
    JSONArray employeeList = new JSONArray();
    employeeList.add(employeeObject);
    employeeList.add(employeeObject2);

    //Write JSON file
    try{
        String strPath          = "employee.json";
        File strFile = new File(strPath);
        boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();
       //File appending
        Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
        //objWriter.write(employeeList.toJSONString());
        objWriter.flush();
        objWriter.close();
        out.flush();
        out.print("OK");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the json file into an `JSONArray`. Add new employee data to this `JSONArray` and write it to the file. I have modified some of your code.

```java
        // Read json file
        String jsonFileStr = new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths
                        .get("PATH TO YOUR EMPLOYEE JSON")),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(jsonFileStr);
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(jsonFileStr);

        // Create employee data to be add to json file
        JSONObject employeeDetails = new JSONObject();
        employeeDetails.put("firstName", "Justin");
        employeeDetails.put("lastName", "Saklitinov");

        JSONObject employeeObject = new JSONObject();
        employeeObject.put("employee", employeeDetails);

        JSONObject employeeDetails2 = new JSONObject();
        employeeDetails2.put("firstName", "Zara");
        employeeDetails2.put("lastName", "Lovez");

        JSONObject employeeObject2 = new JSONObject();
        employeeObject2.put("employee", employeeDetails2);

        // Add data to jsonArray read from json file
        jsonArray.put(employeeObject);
        jsonArray.put(employeeObject2);

        // Writing the jsonArray back to file
        String strPath = "PATH TO EMPLOYEE JSON";
        File strFile = new File(strPath);
        boolean fileCreated = strFile.createNewFile();
        Writer objWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFile));
        objWriter.write(jsonArray.toString());
        objWriter.flush();
        objWriter.close();
```

Note: You might want to reconsider using the same key 'employee' multiple times in the json.

Comment: StandardCharsets.UTF_8 cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Which version of java are you on? Does `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;` compiles for you?

Comment: ok done, i'm already import java.nio, but found error again "The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined"  i'm already import : org.json.simple.*

Comment: sir @Smile can you help me ??

Comment: Didn't know you were using json-simple. I have updated my answer to reflect that. I have updated code to create json array from json str `JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(jsonFileStr);`

Comment: Which version of json simple are you using?

Comment: json-simple-1.1

Comment: You need to use `import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;`

Comment: The method put(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONArray -_-

Comment: Try using `add` method

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Comment: String strPath          = "employee.json";


String jsonFileStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(strPath)),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(jsonFileStr);

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(jsonFileStr);

Comment: make me confused :(

Comment: First try it out as simple java main method, resolve all errors and then integrate code with your web application. And regarding the error you have mentioned, check the logs for complete error.

Answer (score 1):

Try BufferedWriter it open a file in append mode.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( 
                   new FileWriter(fileName, true)); 
            out.write(str); 
            out.close();
```

Comment: oke done append data. but this bracket [ duplicate
[
 {"employee":{"firstName":"Rudi","lastName":"Anton"}},
 {"employee":{"firstName":"Syafira","lastName":"Zarakaria"}}]
[   
 {"employee":{"firstName":"Justin","lastName":"Saklitinov"}},
 {"employee":{"firstName":"Zara","lastName":"Lovez"}}
]

https://pastebin.com/XgyGEDnW

Comment: i want json data inside bracket. Not duplicate bracket

Comment: Sirr ?? can you help me ?

Comment: sorry, i tried to answer as code. But somehow I couldn't. Any way thx.

Answer (score 0):

yes if you are reading as object and writing as on object. It is a overwrite on the same file.

Comment: i want to append data, in same file give me a solution

Comment: i'm also using BufferedWriter, hmm give me example ??

Comment: Try BufferedWriter it open a file in append mode.  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( 
                   new FileWriter(fileName, true)); 
            out.write(str); 
            out.close();

Comment: @PallabRath It is better to update the answer with code rather than writing in comments. Also, This answer looks like more of a comment. You might want to combine both of your answers into a single answer.